# Run an ML training job in local machine and write the logs on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-ai-platform

Is it possible to run an ML training job in local machine and write the logs on Google Cloud (AI Platform/Vertex AI)? Or do I have to run the training using Google Cloud machines to be able to log my training jobs?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You can write logs from your local environment to Google Cloud Logging. You can use the [Cloud Logging libraries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python) for that. Here an example in Go

```
    ctx := context.Background()
    client,err := logging.NewClient(ctx,"<PROJECT_ID>")
    fmt.Println(err)
    l := client.Logger("myLogger")
    l.StandardLogger(logging.Warning).Println("####HELLO THERE*****")
    fmt.Println(l.Flush())
```

---

If your target is to write the stdout and stderr to Cloud Logging as you can do that automatically on Google Cloud, it's not possible out of the box.

However, you can wrap your training execution in another app that listen the stdout and stderr of your training job and which write to Cloud Logging the log entries.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to write logs on AI Platform or Vertex AI if you ran a local training job. AI Platform/Vertex AI only logs operations when a request was made to use cloud resources.

> AI Platform Training logs use an `AuditLog` object and follows the
> same format as other Cloud Audit Logs logs. Logs contain information
> such as:
>
> - The user who made the request, including the email address of that    user.
> - The resource name on which the request was made.
> - The outcome of the request.

So for you to write logs you need to submit an online training job that will use GCP resources.

For further information you can see [AI Platform logged operations](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/audit-logs#types) and [Vertex AI logging audit information](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/audit-logging).

Comment: Can I use this command ```gcloud ai-platform local train ``` as a solution?

Comment: @eng2019 Yes you can use it for local training, but the logs will only be shown in the CLI and will not be stored or shown in GCP logging.